# Highcharts events

Tags: jquery, angular, highcharts

guys, I'm trying to use the afterSetExtremes event of Highcharts. I have this situation

```
...
xAxis: {
            events: {
              afterSetExtremes: this.IntervalHandler
            },
...
```

The problem is that in the function IntervalHandler() i can't call anything that is global such as services, class properties or other function. How can I fix this issue?

This is my file

```
import { Inject, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { statisticheComponent } from "../views/statistiche/statistiche.component";
import { RefreshService } from "../services/refresh.service";
import { InfoGraficiStatistiche } from "../models/info-grafici-statistiche";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-option-chart-principale',
  template: '  <div id="graficoPrincipale" style="width: 100%; height: 225px;"></div>'
})

export class OptionsStatistiche {
  options: Array<Object>;

  @Input() receivedType: string;
  @Input() receivedChart: string;

  prova: string;
  chart: InfoGraficiStatistiche;
  type: string;

  constructor(private _refresh?: RefreshService) {

    this.options = new Array();
    this.prova = "lorenzo";
    this.options['optionsGraficoPrincipale'] = {

      chart: {
        renderTo: 'graficoPrincipale',
        type: 'spline',
        zoomType: 'x'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Andamento tensione',
        floating: true,
        align: 'right',
        x: -20,
        top: 20
      },
      xAxis: {
        events: {
          afterSetExtremes: this.intervalHandler
        },
        type: 'datetime',
        minRange: 3600 * 1000 // one hour
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Volt (V)'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: 'V'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      series: [
        { "name": "R", "data": [] },
        { "name": "S", "data": [] },
        { "name": "T", "data": [] }
      ],
      dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
          type: 'day',
          count: 1,
          text: '1d'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 1,
          text: '1m'
        }, {
          type: 'year',
          count: 1,
          text: '1y'
        }, {
          type: 'all',
          text: 'All'
        }],
        inputEnabled: false, // it supports only days
        selected: 4 // all
      },
      navigator: {
        adaptToUpdatedData: true,
        height: 20,
      },
      scrollbar: {
        liveRedraw: false
      },
      custom_lg: {
        primoCampo: "lorenzo"
      }
    };
    this.options['optionsGraficoDistribuzione'] = {

      chart: {
        renderTo: 'graficoDistribuzione',
        type: 'areaspline'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Distribuzione',
        floating: true,
        align: 'right',
        x: -20,
        top: 20
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: [
          '< 220',
          '220',
          '225',
          '230',
          '235',
          '240',
          '245',
          '> 245'
        ]
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Percentuale (%)'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      },
      series: [
        { "name": "R", "data": [] },
        { "name": "S", "data": [] },
        { "name": "T", "data": [] }
      ],
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      }
    };
    this.options['optionsMisuratoreAnalogico'] = {

      chart: {
        renderTo: 'graficoMisuratoreAnalogico',
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        plotBackgroundColor: {
          linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
          stops: [
            [0, '#FFF4C6'],
            [0.2, '#FFFFFF'],
            [1, '#FFF4C6']
          ]
        },
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        height: 225
      },

      title: {
        text: 'Misurazioni voltmetriche'
      },

      pane: [{
        startAngle: -45,
        endAngle: 45,
        background: null,
        center: ['16%', '80%'],
        size: 200
      }, {
        startAngle: -45,
        endAngle: 45,
        background: null,
        center: ['50%', '80%'],
        size: 200
      }, {
        startAngle: -45,
        endAngle: 45,
        background: null,
        center: ['84%', '80%'],
        size: 200
      }],

      yAxis: [{
        min: 190,
        max: 280,
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        labels: {
          rotation: 'auto',
          distance: 20
        },
        plotBands: [{
          from: 190,
          to: 207,
          color: 'red',
          innerRadius: '100%',
          outerRadius: '105%'
        }, {
          from: 255,
          to: 280,
          color: 'red',
          innerRadius: '100%',
          outerRadius: '105%'
        }],
        pane: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'V<br/><span style="font-size:8px">Channel R</span>',
          y: -20
        }
      }, {
        min: 190,
        max: 280,
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        labels: {
          rotation: 'auto',
          distance: 20
        },
        plotBands: [{
          from: 190,
          to: 207,
          color: 'red',
          innerRadius: '100%',
          outerRadius: '105%'
        }, {
          from: 255,
          to: 280,
          color: 'red',
          innerRadius: '100%',
          outerRadius: '105%'
        }],
        pane: 1,
        title: {
          text: 'V<br/><span style="font-size:8px">Channel S</span>',
          y: -20
        }
      }, {
        min: 190,
        max: 280,
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        labels: {
          rotation: 'auto',
          distance: 20
        },
        plotBands: [{
          from: 190,
          to: 207,
          color: 'red',
          innerRadius: '100%',
          outerRadius: '105%'
        }, {
          from: 255,
          to: 280,
          color: 'red',
          innerRadius: '100%',
          outerRadius: '105%'
        }],
        pane: 2,
        title: {
          text: 'V<br/><span style="font-size:8px">Channel T</span>',
          y: -20
        }
      }],

      plotOptions: {
        gauge: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.y:.2f} V',
            y: 30
          },
          dial: {
            radius: '100%'
          }
        }
      },


      series: [{
        data: [230],
        yAxis: 0
      }, {
        data: [230],
        yAxis: 1
      }, {
        data: [230],
        yAxis: 2
      }]

    };
    this.options['optionsGraficoTorta'] = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'graficoMediaPerFase',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
      }, title: {
        text: 'Media per fase'
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.2f} V</b>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000',
            connectorColor: '#000000',
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y:.2f} V'
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Media per fase',
        data: []
      }]
    };
    this.options['optionsGraficoMediaOraria'] = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'graficoMediaOraria',
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Media oraria',
        floating: true,
        align: 'right',
        x: -20,
        top: 20
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: [
          '0',
          '1',
          '2',
          '3',
          '4',
          '5',
          '6',
          '7',
          '8',
          '9',
          '10',
          '11',
          '12'
        ]
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Volt (V)'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: 'V'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      },
      series: [
        { "name": "R", "data": [] },
        { "name": "S", "data": [] },
        { "name": "T", "data": [] }
      ],
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      }
    };
    this.options['optionsGraficoMediaGiornaliera'] = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'graficoMediaGiornaliera',
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Media giornaliera',
        floating: true,
        align: 'right',
        x: -20,
        top: 20
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: [
          'Lunedi\'',
          'Martedi\'',
          'Mercoledi\'',
          'Giovedi\'',
          'Venerdi\'',
          'Sabato',
          'Domenica'
        ],
        labels: {
          rotation: -45,
          align: 'right',
          style: {
            fontSize: '10px'
          }
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Volt (V)'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: 'V'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      },
      series: [
        { "name": "R", "data": [] },
        { "name": "S", "data": [] },
        { "name": "T", "data": [] }
      ],
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      }
    };
    this.options['optionsGraficoMediaMensile'] = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'graficoMediaMensile',
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Media mensile',
        floating: true,
        align: 'right',
        x: -20,
        top: 20
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: [
          'Gennaio',
          'Febbraio',
          'Marzo',
          'Aprile',
          'Maggio',
          'Giugno',
          'Luglio',
          'Agosto',
          'Settembre',
          'Ottobre',
          'Novembre',
          'Dicembre'
        ],
        labels: {
          rotation: -45,
          align: 'right',
          style: {
            fontSize: '10px'
          }
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Volt (V)'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: 'V'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      },
      series: [
        { "name": "R", "data": [] },
        { "name": "S", "data": [] },
        { "name": "T", "data": [] }
      ],
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      }
    };
  }

  getOption(index: string) {
    console.log("prima stampa**************+:", this.prova);

    return this.options[index];
  }

  setLabelAmpereOption() {
    let ampere: string = "Ampere (A)";
    this.options['optionsGraficoPrincipale'].title.text = "Andamento corrente";
    this.options['optionsMisuratoreAnalogico'].title.text = "Misurazioni amperometriche";
    this.options['optionsGraficoMediaOraria'].yAxis.title.text = ampere;
    this.options['optionsGraficoMediaGiornaliera'].yAxis.title.text = ampere;
    this.options['optionsGraficoMediaMensile'].yAxis.title.text = ampere;
  }

  setData(index: string, dati: any, i: number) {
    this.options[index].series[i].data = dati;
  }

  setOptionPerEventoModificaIntervallo() {
    alert("funza");
    }

  intervalHandler(e) {
    let prova: string = "Arrivo Raga";
    console.log(e);
    let startDate: number = Math.trunc(e.userMin);
    let endDate: number = Math.trunc(e.userMax);
    console.log("start date: ", startDate);
    console.log("end date: ", endDate);
    console.log(this.prova);

    this.stampaProva(prova);
    // this.setOptionPerEventoModificaIntervallo();
    //     this._refresh.aggiornaGrafico(this.receivedChart, this.receivedType, "ora_giorno", startDate, endDate).subscribe((res) => {
    //     this.chart['chartPrincipale'].series[0].setData(res.data);
    //     this.chart['chartPrincipale'].hideLoading();
    // });
  }

  stampaProva(prova: string){
    console.log("Stampa Prova: " , prova);
  }

}
```

Comment: Bind this to the handler: this.IntervalHandler.bind(this)

Comment: i tried your solution but it doesn't work:( i forgot that i'm using Angular 2, have you got other solutions?

Comment: It is not related to any framework - it is a js native function for binding this to the function. It works will angular 2 - see example https://plnkr.co/edit/sV0gEBXqvQ4dp8FnvYXK?p=info